# How to split a python list based on specific characters like spaces and forward slashes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split, concatenation

Suppose that you have the python list:

```
a = ["a", " ", "b", "i", "g", " ", "d", "o", "g", " ", "b", "i", "t", " ", "m", "e"]
```

Is there a way to split this list such that you get:

```
a = [["a"],["big"],["dog"],["bit"],["me"]]
```

or similar?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/itertools.html):

```
a = ['a', ' ', 'b', 'i', 'g', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'g', ' ',
     'b', 'i', 't', ' ', 'm', 'e']

from itertools import groupby

out = [[''.join(g)] for k, g in groupby(a, lambda x: x!=' ') if k]
```

output: `[['a'], ['big'], ['dog'], ['bit'], ['me']]`

Comment: Tweaking `lambda x: x!=' '` to `lambda x: x not in {' ', '/'}` to handle the case of splitting on both spaces and forward slashes as mentioned in the title.

Comment: @ShadowRanger well spotted, I have to admit I had not seen that ;)

Comment: Hey, you'd already given The Correct Answer™ I was planning to post (I love me some `itertools`), had to nitpick something while I was up-voting. :-)

Answer (score 12):

Something like this:

```
>>> a = ["a", " ", "b", "i", "g", " ", "d", "o", "g", " ", "b", "i", "t", " ", "m", "e"]
>>> ''.join(a)
'a big dog bit me'
>>> [[word] for word in ''.join(a).split()]
[['a'], ['big'], ['dog'], ['bit'], ['me']]
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this in one line:

```
[[i] for i in "".join(a).split()]
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution:

```py
a = ["a", " ", "b","i","g"," ","d","o", "g"," ","b","i","t"," ","m","e"]
[*map(lambda x: [x], ''.join(a).split())]

#> [['a'], ['big'], ['dog'], ['bit'], ['me']]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ["a", " ", "b", "i", "g", " ", "d", "o", "g", " ", "b", "i", "t", " ", "m", "e"]
l = []
for i in ''.join(a).split():
    nl = [i]
    l.append(nl)
print(l)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) solution yet. That should be rectified.

```
a = ['a', ' ', 'b', 'i', 'g', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'g', ' ',
     'b', 'i', 't', ' ', 'm', 'e']

def f(acc, x):
  if x not in [' ', '/']: return (acc[0] + x, acc[1])
  elif acc[0]: return ("", acc[1] + [acc[0]])
  else: return acc

last, rest = reduce(f, a, ('', []))

rest + [last] if last else rest
# ['a', 'big', 'dog', 'bit', 'me']

a = [' ', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'o', '/', ' ', 'b', 'a', 'r', ' ']

last, rest = reduce(f, a, ('', []))

rest + [last] if last else rest
# ['foo', 'bar']
```